# Как передать в сериализатор словарь

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Я использую django и django rest framework. Подскажите, пожалуста, как можно в сериализатор передать объект не из модели, а обычный словарь?

сериализуемый объект:

```
class SerializerClass:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(dictonary=entries['dict_example'])

exmaple = SerializerClass(dict_example={'a': 'aaaaa', 'b': 'bbbbb'})
```

сериализатор:

```
class MySerializer(Serializer):
    my_list = DictField(child=CharField())
```

viewSet:

```
class MyViewSet(ListModelMixin):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    queryset = exmaple.dict_example
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    serializer_class = MySerializer
```

Мне необходимо вывести содержимое словаря по get запросу. На текущий момент падает с ошибкой `AttributeError 'dict' object has no attribute 'model'`. Если я правильно понимаю, то необходимо определить свою модель  SerializerClass если да, то как это правильно сделать?

Comment: Почему нельзя использовать `json.dumps(dict_example)`?

Comment: Как при обращении к эндпойнту который обрабатывает MyViewSet использовать json.dumps(dict_example)

Comment: endpoint тоже вы писали?

Comment: пытаюсь написать

Comment: а почему бы не написать его так, чтобы он обрабатывал JSON? Это общепризнанный стандарт, работа с ним в Python совершенно тривиальна.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

для решения данной задачи возможны варианты:

1) без использования сериализатора
viewSet будет выглядеть так:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet)):
    http_method_names = ('get',)
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def list(self, request):
        result = dict() # передаем сюда нужный словарь
        return Response(result, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

маршруты будут выглядеть так:

```
dict_router.register(r'get_dict', MyViewSet, base_name='get_dict')
```

в этом случае будет вывод вида:

```
{
   key1: value1,
   key2: value2,
}
```

---

2) с использованием сериализатора (тут сериализуется словарь с объектами):
сериализатор будет выглядеть так:

```
class SerializeObject(object):
    def __init__(self, code, description):
        self.code = code
        self.description = description

my_dict = {       # можно сделать генератор
    1: SerializeObject(code1, description1),
    2: SerializeObject(code2, description2),
}

class MySerializer(Serializer):
    code = CharField(max_length=100)
    description = CharField(max_length=100)
```

viewSet будет выглядеть так:

```
class MyViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def list(self, request, version):
        serializer = MySerializer(instance=my_dict, many=True) # тут нужно передать словарь
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

маршруты такие же как и в предыдущем случае:

```
dict_router.register(r'get_dict', MyViewSet, base_name='get_dict')
```

в этом случае вывод будет такой:

```
{
   1:{code1: description1},
   2:{code2: description2},
}
```